# How can I add a static timestamp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time

I want to add a static timestamp (for a list or social media app for example) using plain javascript. Currently I have it like this:

```
  const d = new Date();
  const time = d.toLocaleTimeString();
```

The problem is that when you refresh, it also refreshes the time and sets it to your current time, not the time that the item was posted. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

use time like this in reactjs,
using useState, so wont get updated, you can use `time` variable,

```
const [time, setTime] = useState(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());

if(localStorage.getItem("time")){
    setTime(localStorage.getItem("time"))
} else {
    localStorage.setItem("time", time);
    setTime(time)
}
```

Comment: Alright thanks so much, will test it out.